# Aligning UL block to the bottom of a DIV block

Tags: html, css

I'm entirely new at this, so if I have stated an unclear question, please ask for clarification.

I have difficulties with placing a ul block at the bottom of a div block. I have researched the answers to the questions that are very similar to mine, but for some reasons, their suggestions and approaches do not work on my codes. I'll provide the following link: http://jsfiddle.net/bKh5L/

**HTML**

```
<div id='tabs'>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Me</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#tabs{
    position: relative;
}

#tabs > ul{
    height: 100px; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom; 0;    
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: red;
}

*{
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1px dashed lightblue;
}
```

Please, tell me where have I gone wrong and provide the elaborative explanation if you are feeling generous, so I can understand not just how the code work but the concept of vertical alignment itself.

Comment: Do you want about us to be under home?

Comment: No. What I want is to have all li blocks to be aligned at the bottom #tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `height` from the `ul` and set it on the #tabs div:

```
#tabs{
  position: relative;
  height: 100px; 
}

#tabs > ul{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;    
}
```

Also you have a typo error on `bottom:`. Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bKh5L/3/)

Another option to keep the `height` on ul but without `position:absolute` :

```
#tabs > ul:before {
  display:inline-block;
  content:" ";
  height:100%;
}
li{
  vertical-align:bottom;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Another [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bKh5L/8/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent hours figuring out what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. There's a typo in `bottom;0;`
2. Give the parent an absolute height as well.

[Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/bKh5L/7/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this seeing `bottom:0px;` which actually in your fiddle was written wrongly as `bottom;0;`:

### <kbd>[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bKh5L/6/)</kbd>

Comment: Bloody hell... Thanks for the catch. Appreicated it!